# Cartoon with a boy that has a red rhino monster and chases and fights other monsters

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

What cartoon (with the word kaiju was in the title) has a boy that has a red rhino monster and chases and fights other monsters?

All I can remember is the boy had (I think) red and black hair and he bonded with a rhino that was red and black. He used a glove to control the monsters. His friends help him out.

Comment: So, how were there "Kaiju" involved? Was it actually related to the Godzilla Kaiju series?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [Kaijudo! Rise of the Duel Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaijudo). The young protagonist travels around with his friends, battling other Kaiju with his rhino-like monster which he controls with a glove.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Could it be *Flint The Time Detective*? I've asked similar question in one of my comments, about "Hoom daga, hin daga" opening song and got that show.

Here's opening:

> Plot: The series is centered around the adventures of Flint
>   Hammerhead, a boy from the prehistoric era who was resurrected from
>   his fossil prison and became a Time Detective, although his competency
>   as a detective is dubious. Much like Inspector Gadget, much of the
>   heavy thinking is done by Flint's friends Sarah and Tony Goodman who
>   accompany him on his adventures. Flint, however, pulled his weight in
>   battle when he would fight with the aid of his father Rocky Hammerhead
>   whose partial resurrection left him a sentient, talking rock with a
>   face. Rocky, fashioned into a hammer for Flint, served Flint as both
>   sturdy weapon and adviser, the latter both in and out of battle.
>   Flint's job as a Time Detective was to go back in time and convince
>   time-shifters, cute, collectible creatures to ally with him to protect
>   the timeline.
>
> Usually, he fought against Petra Fina and her cronies Dino and Mite
>   (very reminiscent of Marjo, Grocky, and Walther from *Time Bokan*),
>   servants of the Dark Lord. The Dark Lord himself sought to use the
>   time-shifters' powers to invade the Land of Time, the creatures' home
>   realm from whence he had scattered them. Similar to *Pokémon* or
>   *Digimon*, time-shifters originate as small, cute creatures who can
>   "shape-shift" into much stronger forms for a time before reverting.
>   This usually took two forms: an evil form induced by the Dark Lord's
>   magic (in the form of the Petra Stamp or Uglinator's mark) and a good
>   one brought forth by Flint and his team.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia, *Flint The Time Detective*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint_the_Time_Detective)