# Cartoon series with Infinity gauntlet-like worn by a teenage boy

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, powers

For years I have been looking for a series which I saw one episode of when I was sick at home as a kid around 6-7 years ago. It was (I think dubbed) German if that somehow helps!

The show was about a teenage boy who wore some glove with slots in it. And for every slot there was a magic stone which each gave the wearer certain powers. 
From my memory it was very much like Marvel's Infinity Gauntlet but less powerful and as a cartoon series. This boy (if I remember correctly) used the powers of the glove to capture roaming monsters.

I remember parts of the episode I watched:

- It was about that boy

  - I think he had some other character like father or uncle or something who had shelves with all the captured monsters in jars
- Now that episode there were 1-2 'mind monsters' who could mind control normal people

  - They probably were captured in a previous episode
  - In this one they escaped because someone accidentally came too close and was brainwashed
  - So I think the boy had to catch them again after they escaped but I remember at the end there was another kid with the same incomplete glove
- Now that I think about it it all seemed to be some kind of training to earn/control the different stones and their powers

Answer (score 8):

I have been looking all morning for the answer to this and it’s Danny Phantom! "[Reality Trip](https://dannyphantom.fandom.com/wiki/Reality_Trip)", the episode/movie with [Freakshow](https://dannyphantom.fandom.com/wiki/Freakshow) and the circus and Danny has to use the [Reality Gauntlet](https://dannyphantom.fandom.com/wiki/Reality_Gauntlet) to capture monsters or something like that and four stones have to go in it! The gauntlet allowed the wearer to control people's minds as long as all four gems with all separate powers were in the gauntlet.

[image: Reality Gauntlet on display with gems below it]

Answer (score 3):

Could it be *[Kaijudo: Rise of the Duel Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaijudo)*? It has a main character, Ray, who wears a magic gauntlet with a gem on the back, and fights monsters. It was vaguely based off *Duel Monsters*, but was commissioned by Wizards of the Coast, otherwise known for games like *Magic: the Gathering*.

Comment: If so, it's a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162516/what-cartoon-has-a-boy-that-has-a-red-rhino-monster-and-chases-and-fights-other. If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: No unfortunately this is not the show I'm looking for.

Comment: @SkyK: Could you clarify your question in ways in which this answer does not fit?

Comment: well, this indeed is a series with a teenage boy wearing a glove fighting monsters but it is not the one I'm looking for. As far as I can see your suggestion hasn't got anything to do with magic stones which can be put into the glove enhancing the wearers power. Along with other things. I have the feeling that it was less of a known thing monsters exist in 'my' series and the protagonist was catching them rather than dueling with said monsters.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be [*s-CRY-ed*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/168/sCRYed) (2001)! Has mecha but a kid that has a gauntlet looking arm with a magic stone

[image: s-CRY-ed poster showing the gauntlet]

Answer (score 0):

So I think your thinking of [*Huntik*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers). It's been a while since I've watched it but it has an uncle character and stones or amulets he had to collect with monsters inside. It's been too long since I've watched it so I don't have much info. I don't really remember anything about a gauntlet though.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question is very clear about the gauntlet being a major part of the show, and it really doesn't sound like that's part of Huntik.  (And it seems like Lok only wielded a single amulet at a time instead of using a collection of them.)

Comment: Fair point. Just figured I'd chip in. Ya know, maybe he miss remembered something and when he reads all these different things people post one might stick out. I tip my hat to you for still moderating this even though the question was asked over 2 years ago. I really hope the answer is found! Cant wait ^v^

Answer (score -3):

[Monster Allergy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Allergy_(TV_series)). It think that's the TV show you're talking about.

> Monster Allergy is based on the comic book series of the same name.
>   The series follows 12-year-old Ezekiel Zick (called Zick) who suffers
>   from various allergies and has the ability to see the invisible
>   monsters that live among us. Along with help of his best friend, Elena
>   Potato and his talking cat, Timothy, Zick hopes to hone his powers to
>   one day become a Monster Tamer just like his dad, Zobedja Zick

Comment: Hi there. As it stands, this does not provide an actual answer to the question: could you [edit] into your answer why you think that might be it?

Comment: Well, it *might* provide an answer - but, there's no information as to why you believe it's a match. That helps the asker decide if it's a match or not, and can even prompt more information from the asker, even if the answer is wrong. From your answer, we only have the name of the show - which, since the asker saw it in German, might not be an obvious match to the name in English.

Comment: Basically the reasons I think it's a match because in the show the child has his father and uncle/friend being that were actually captured by the monster, at some point he obtains the glove which is similar to the infinity like gauntlet and he gains new powers which take shape in the form of the crystals that fit into the slots in the gauntlet.